# Java: String.length() > 0 and Array.size() > 0 shorthand?

Tags: java, arrays, shorthand

There must be a way to shorthandcode this. I use it all the time and its not beautiful at all.

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add( "Foo" );
items.add( "Bar" );

String zxc;
```

I know this exist

```
for( String s : items ) {
    zxc = s;
}
```

But when using indexes there must be a way to shorthand this

```
for( int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++ ) {
    zxc = items.get( i );
}
```

Comment: neither of the loops do anything. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. If you really need the indexes, you have to use the traditional `for`.

Comment: The title of this question doesn't really make sense given the description. Where are you testing for a string length greater than 0?

Comment: I am not attempting to do anything more than shortening the code. This is just an example. I will add logic to it.

Comment: The `for each` loop is meant to be the simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.
The only small tweak you can do is define a size var:

```
int iSize = items.size();
for( int i = 0; i < iSize; i++ ) {}
```

This is so you don't have to run size() method on every iteration. Also this is as basic / shorthanded looping as it gets and you should know how to write these lines in < 2 secs

Comment: Or even `for(int i = 0, n = items.size(); i < n; i++ ) {}` but i think the JIT compiler will make such an optimization by itself...

Comment: @Benjamin Your solution is still better because it limits the scope of `n` to the `for` loop.

Comment: @Ajk_P The main purpose of the shorthand looping idiom isn't to save typing but to make the code more explicit and to eradicate mistakes like this: `for (int i = 0; i < foo; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < bar; i++) { ... } }`

Comment: I understand the profit of not running the method size() every time but it makes more code.

Answer (score 1):

How about `!String.isEmpty()` and `!List.isEmpty()`?

`String` and `List` defines an `isEmpty()` method, you just have to negate it to tell if length or size is greater than 0.

```
String s = "asdf";
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("one", "two");

if (!s.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("String has characters.");
if (!l.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("List has elements.");
```

Comment: This answers the question in the title, but the question body is about something different.  Consider reading the body before FGITWing.

Comment: This is good. Any way to add items to that? Like l.add( item );?

Comment: @JonasB `Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. If you want a modifiable `List`, use `ArrayList` like `List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your own index.

```
int i=0;
for( String s : items ) {
   doStuff();
   i++;
}
```

Comment: True. But that code is probably just as long :/

Comment: Agreed. But I think all anyone can provide is alternatives so I thought I would contribute one

Comment: Ofcourse. Im probably not the only one looking for alternatives.